# Mass Find and Replace Issue - Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace

I am trying to create a macro in order to do a mass find and replace across multiple word documents. I have found this one on the net and altered it to also apply for graphics however I keep getting a run time error (5174) saying that the file could not be found (even though it is definitely in the folder).

I believe the issue is this: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/212664 but am having a bit of trouble implementing it into my Macro as simply adding ".docx" after every single Fname doesn't seem to work.

I have limited experience with Macros so apologies if this is a novice question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim Directory As String
Dim FType As String
Dim FName As String

Directory = "C:\Users\pieria\Desktop\TempPics"
FType = "*.docx"

ChDir Directory
FName = Dir(FType)
' for each file you find, run this loop
Do While FName <> ""
' open the file
Documents.Open FileName:=FName  '<--Error is supposedly here 

' search and replace the company name
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "CompanyA"
    .MatchCase = True
    .Replacement.Text = "CompanyB"
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' save and close the current document
ActiveDocument.Close wdSaveChanges

' look for next matching file
FName = Dir
Loop 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the current instance not being aware of the `ChDir` you did. You better specify the full path when opening the file:

```
 ' open the file
 Documents.Open FileName:= Directory & "\" & FName
```

I concatenate the string in `Directory` and `FName` with the `&` operator.

So if `Directory` contains `C:\Users\pieria\Desktop\TempPics` and `FName` contains `First.docx` with `&` you create a new string `C:\Users\pieria\Desktop\TempPics\First.docx`

Notice the `\` I added between the directory name and the filename...

Comment: I have another issue that you may be able to help with... Im also trying to do a "find and replace for images in footers. The code I have only seems to work for images not in footers!

Comment: I cant seem to add it in the comment section so will open another thread and post the link

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/980800/mass-find-and-replace-for-pictures-macro-microsoft-word-2013