# Mass Find and Replace for Pictures Macro - Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace

I have this macro that is able to do a mass find and replace across multiple word documents. I am able to do a find and replace for pictures (within a header) but when I implemented it within my macro code it seems to just ignore it and not find and replace any pictures. I am unsure as to why this is the case since there are no errors. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

```
Sub FindandReplaceTextPic()
Dim Directory As String
Dim FType As String
Dim FName As String

Directory = "C:\Users\pieria\Desktop\TempPics"
FType = "*.docx"

ChDir Directory
FName = Dir(FType)
' for each file you find, run this loop
Do While FName <> ""
    ' open the file
    Documents.Open FileName:=Directory & "\" & FName

    ' search and replace the company name
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "CompanyA"
        .MatchCase = True
        .Replacement.Text = "CompanyB"
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'search and replace picture from clipboard
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = "^g"
   .Replacement.Text = "^c"
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = False
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    ' save and close the current document
    ActiveDocument.Close wdSaveChanges

    ' look for next matching file
    FName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through each storyRange (including headers) and use the .Find method of the range instead of the selection object.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Find and Replace Images in MS Word**

MS-Word can help in the above given scenario. There is an automatic way to find all the images in a document and then replace them all with a new image.

Please note that this method will find all the images and it will replace all of them with a new one. With this method, we can not be selective about images. Here are the steps:

1. Open the Microsoft Word document in which replacement is to be done.
2. Insert the new image at the top of the document.
3. Select the newly inserted image and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
4. Now delete the newly inserted image.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the “Find and Replace” box.
6. Put `^g` in the “Find what” box and `^c` in the “Replace with” box

Method of finding all images and replacing them with a new one.

Now press “Replace All” button to see the magic!

All images have been replaced in MS Word.

You will see that all the images in the document will be replaced with the new image. Of course, the replacement operation will also replace the images that you did not want to replace. In such a case you may need to re-insert the images that were not to be replaced. This method is useful in a scenario where:

1. the document contains only those images that are to be replaced
2. the document contains a large number of images that need to be replaced and a smaller number of images that should not be replaced

The first scenario is straightforward. In the second scenario, you’ll be doing much less manual work by re-inserting images that were replaced as a side-effect.

The method works by replacing all graphics (denoted by `^g`) with the clipboard content (denoted by `^c`). Therefore, essentially, you can replace all images with anything that you can copy to clipboard.

To keep your document’s pagination intact, you should use the same size new image.

I hope this MS-Word tip was useful for you. If you have any question on this topic, please feel free to ask me through comments. I will try to assist you. Thank you for using TechWelkin.

**Related Articles for More Information:**

1. MS Word: How to Find and Replace Numbers, Digits, Numerals
2. Find and Replace Formatting in MS-Word
3. Multiple Find and Replace in MS Word Using Macro
4. Replace Line, Paragraph, Carriage Break in MS Word
5. Type ° Degree Symbol in MS Word, HTML, Unicode
6. MS Word: How to Select Vertical Rectangular Area

Comment: (1) Is this copied from somewhere?   If so, you must say where — name the source and link to it.  (2) If you’re going to refer to related articles, please link to them.